# Preencher checkbox do PDF com o iText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itextsharp, itext

Olá!
Estou tentando checar um checbox do meu PDF, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso corretamente.
Em vez de checar apenas um dos checkbox, ele sempre está checando todos os 3

O que eu gostaria:
 [image: img]

O que estou obtendo: 
 [image: img]

PDF no editor do Adobe Reader.
Todos os 3 checkbox tem o mesmo nome, isso que está dando o problema:
 [image: img]

Pelo que andei pesquisando, parece que esse Valor de Exportação tem algo a ver com isso.
[image: img]

Meu código:

```cs
private static void CreatePdf(string output)
{
    using var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("CheckTest.pdf"), new PdfWriter(output));
    var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
    var check = form.GetField("Check");
    check.SetValue("01");
}
```

Link do PDF que usei no exemplo: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shZ8z5QDsgzuVNU2QIY9wfUzpTNGNbLi/view?usp=sharing)

Alguém consegue me ajudar a marcar corretamente o checkbox?

Obrigado!

Comment: talvez porque todos tenham o memo nome/id? tentou `form.GetField("Check#1");`? Verificou o que está sendo atribuído à `var check `, não é uma coleção?

Comment: Não é uma coleção e sim um `PdfButtonFormField`. Tentei pegar com `form.GetField("Check#1")` sim, mãs não retorna nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa questão foi resolvida aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858117/fill-pdf-check-field-with-itext7/64893012#64893012

Resumindo o que foi respondido lá, em vez de preencher o checkbox assim

```cs
check.SetValue("01");
```

eu devo preencher dessa forma

```cs
check.SetValue("01", false);
```